# JSON error with iOS manipulation

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON app, but I think I am having a problem with my JSON code. I have checked my JSON on different validators and they all say that my JSON is valid. Here is my error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

My JSON is uploaded to http://www.annabellesykes.byethost11.com/shailenewoodleyfansappjson.json

My JSON processing code is:

```
class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

var siteURL = "http://www.annabellesykes.byethost11.com/shailenewoodleyfansappjson.json"
var items = [Item]()
var item:Item!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getLatestNews()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].title
    cell.dateLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].date
    cell.contentLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].content

    cell.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 999
    cell.contentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.contentLabel.numberOfLines = 3
    cell.dateLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.dateLabel.numberOfLines = 999

    cell.dateLabel.sizeToFit()

    return cell
}

func getLatestNews() {

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: siteURL)!)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            self.items = self.parseJsonData(data)

            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Item] {

    var items = [Item]()

    do {

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

        let jsonItems = jsonResult?["items"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonItem in jsonItems {
            let item = Item()
            item.title = jsonItem["title"] as! String
            item.content = jsonItem["content"] as! String
            item.date = jsonItem["date"] as! String
            items.append(item)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return items
}
}
```

Comment: This page returns HTML, not JSON. It shows JSON in a browser because the page has a JavaScript that replaces the HTML with the JSON. This is the issue: your code gets the HTML, not the JSON.

Comment: @EricD. So how should I interpret this into JSON?

Comment: You have to fetch data from an endpoint that gives JSON, not from a dynamic HTML page constructed with JavaScript. The issue is not with your code, it's with the source.

Comment: Like Mehul's answer? @EricD.

Comment: The issue is at server side, yes. The server creates an HTML page instead of delivering JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code and after debugging it looks that you have extra space at starting of each and every key in your response. This shows that there is something problem at json encoder at server side. Possibly this is bug in alamofire with using it with django at serverside.

Comment: That makes sense. I just switched my FTP server, and the one I was using before seemed to work, but not this one.

Comment: The JSON response we got in the browser *is ok*, you can verify it with http://jsonlint.com/ for example.

Comment: I have validated it and its fine. @EricD.

Comment: @SWFApp Yes, that's what I was telling to Mehul. :)

Comment: There is a problem with the server side, yes, but it's unrelated to extra space, since we've asserted that the JSON *is valid*. The problem is that the server, when not consumed by browser, delivers HTML instead of the JSON.